# Error when deleting or editing form data from database using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

Everything in my code seems to work just fine, except when I try to edit/delete already queried data.

Delete does nothing... and edit gives me an error shown below:

[image: Error when attempting to edit]

Current code: (login/database information missing for privacy reasons):

```
    // Create connection
    $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $cdb->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully <br>";

    $thisPHP = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    if (!isset($_POST['btnEdit'])) {
        echo <<<EOT
        <form action="$thisPHP" method="POST"><br>
        Employer ID: <input type="text" name="eid"><br>
        Company Name: <input type="text" name="compname"><br>
        Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
        Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br> 
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Position: <input type="text" name="position"> Description: <input type="text" name="description"> 
        Location: <select name="state" id="state">
            <option value="">--</option>
            <option value="AL">AL</option> 
            <option value="AK">AK</option> 
            <option value="AZ">AZ</option> 
            <option value="AR">AR</option> 
            <option value="CA">CA</option> 
            <option value="CO">CO</option> 
            <option value="CT">CT</option> 
            <option value="DE">DE</option> 
            <option value="FL">FL</option> 
            <option value="GA">GA</option> 
            <option value="HI">HI</option> 
            <option value="ID">ID</option> 
            <option value="IL">IL</option> 
            <option value="IN">IN</option> 
            <option value="IA">IA</option> 
            <option value="KS">KS</option> 
            <option value="KY">KY</option> 
            <option value="LA">LA</option> 
            <option value="ME">ME</option> 
            <option value="MD">MD</option> 
            <option value="MA">MA</option> 
            <option value="MI">MI</option> 
            <option value="MN">MN</option> 
            <option value="MS">MS</option> 
            <option value="MO">MO</option> 
            <option value="MT">MT</option> 
            <option value="NE">NE</option> 
            <option value="NV">NV</option> 
            <option value="NH">NH</option> 
            <option value="NJ">NJ</option> 
            <option value="NM">NM</option> 
            <option value="NY">NY</option> 
            <option value="NC">NC</option> 
            <option value="ND">ND</option> 
            <option value="OH">OH</option> 
            <option value="OK">OK</option> 
            <option value="OR">OR</option> 
            <option value="PA">PA</option> 
            <option value="RI">RI</option> 
            <option value="SC">SC</option> 
            <option value="SD">SD</option> 
            <option value="TN">TN</option> 
            <option value="TX">TX</option> 
            <option value="UT">UT</option> 
            <option value="VT">VT</option> 
            <option value="WA">WA</option> 
            <option value="WV">WV</option> 
            <option value="WI">WI</option> 
            <option value="WY">WY</option> 
            <option value="DC">DC</option> 
        </select> <br>
        Skill: <select name="skill1">
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience1">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Skill: <select name="skill2">
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience2">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Skill: <select name="skill3">
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience3">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Need: <input type="radio" name="need" value="Urgent" checked> Urgent (<1 Month) <br>
             <input type="radio" name="need" value="Soon"> Soon (1-3 Months) <br>
             <input type="radio" name="need" value="Upcoming"> Upcoming (3+ Month) <br>
        <input type="submit" name="btnAdd" value="Add"> <br>
        <hr>
        </form>  
EOT;
    }

    $eid = $_POST["eid"];
    $compname = $_POST["compname"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $location = $_POST["state"];
    $skill1 = $_POST["skill1"];
    $experience1 = $_POST["experience1"];
    $skill2 = $_POST["skill2"];
    $experience2 = $_POST["experience2"];
    $skill3 = $_POST["skill3"];
    $experience3 = $_POST["experience3"];
    $need = $_POST["need"];

    if (isset($_POST['btnAdd'])){
        if (!empty($eid)){
            // Form sql string
            $location = $_POST["state"];
            $sql = "insert into Employer (EmployerID, CompName, Address, Phone, Email, PosTitle, Description, Location, Skill1, Experience1, Skill2, Experience2, Skill3, Experience3, Need) values ('$eid', '$compname', '$address', '$phone', '$email', '$position', '$description', '$location', '$skill1', '$experience1', '$skill2', '$experience2', '$skill3', '$experience3', '$need')";
            if ($db->query ($sql) == TRUE) {
                echo "Record added <br>";
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['btnDelete'])) {
        $eid= $_POST['eid'];
        $sql = "delete from Employer where eid='$eid'";
        echo mysql_error();
        if ($db->query ($sql) == TRUE)
        {
            echo "Record deleted <br>";
        }
    } 

   if (isset($_POST['btnEdit'])) {
        $sql = "select * from Employer where eid='$eid'";
        if (($result = $db->query ($sql)) == TRUE)
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $eid = $row["EmployerID"];
                $compname = $row["CompName"];
                $address = $row["Address"];
                $phone = $row["Phone"];
                $email = $row["Email"];
                $position = $row["PosTitle"];
                $description = $row["Description"];
                $location = $row["Location"];
                $skill1 = $row["Skill1"];
                $experience1 = $row["Experience1"];
                $skill2 = $row["Skill2"];
                $experience2 = $row["Experience2"];
                $skill3 = $row["Skill3"];
                $experience3 = $row["Experience3"];
                $need = $row["Need"];
            }
        }


        echo <<<EOE
        <form action="$thisPHP" method="POST">
        Employer ID: <input type="text" name="eid" value='$eid'> 
        Company Name: <input type="text" name="compname" value='$compname'> 
        Address: <input type="text" name="address" value='$address'> 
        Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" value='$phone'> 
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" value='$email'><br>
        Position: <input type="text" name="position" value='$position'> 
        Description: <input type="text" name="description" value='$description'> 
        Location: <select name="state" id="state" value='$location'>
            <option value="">--</option>
            <option value="AL">AL</option> 
            <option value="AK">AK</option> 
            <option value="AZ">AZ</option> 
            <option value="AR">AR</option> 
            <option value="CA">CA</option> 
            <option value="CO">CO</option> 
            <option value="CT">CT</option> 
            <option value="DE">DE</option> 
            <option value="FL">FL</option> 
            <option value="GA">GA</option> 
            <option value="HI">HI</option> 
            <option value="ID">ID</option> 
            <option value="IL">IL</option> 
            <option value="IN">IN</option> 
            <option value="IA">IA</option> 
            <option value="KS">KS</option> 
            <option value="KY">KY</option> 
            <option value="LA">LA</option> 
            <option value="ME">ME</option> 
            <option value="MD">MD</option> 
            <option value="MA">MA</option> 
            <option value="MI">MI</option> 
            <option value="MN">MN</option> 
            <option value="MS">MS</option> 
            <option value="MO">MO</option> 
            <option value="MT">MT</option> 
            <option value="NE">NE</option> 
            <option value="NV">NV</option> 
            <option value="NH">NH</option> 
            <option value="NJ">NJ</option> 
            <option value="NM">NM</option> 
            <option value="NY">NY</option> 
            <option value="NC">NC</option> 
            <option value="ND">ND</option> 
            <option value="OH">OH</option> 
            <option value="OK">OK</option> 
            <option value="OR">OR</option> 
            <option value="PA">PA</option> 
            <option value="RI">RI</option> 
            <option value="SC">SC</option> 
            <option value="SD">SD</option> 
            <option value="TN">TN</option> 
            <option value="TX">TX</option> 
            <option value="UT">UT</option> 
            <option value="VT">VT</option> 
            <option value="WA">WA</option> 
            <option value="WV">WV</option> 
            <option value="WI">WI</option> 
            <option value="WY">WY</option> 
            <option value="DC">DC</option> 
        </select> <br>
        Skill: <select name="skill1" value='$skill1'>
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience1" value='$experience1'>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Skill: <select name="skill2" value='$skill2'>
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience2" value='$experience'>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Skill: <select name="skill3" value='$skill3'>
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience3" value='$experience3'>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Need: <input type="radio" name="need" value="Urgent" checked value='$name'> Urgent (<1 Month) <br>
             <input type="radio" name="need" value="Soon" value='$name'> Soon (1-3 Months) <br>
             <input type="radio" name="need" value="Upcoming" value='$name'> Upcoming (3+ Month) <br>
        <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update"> <br>
        <hr>
        </form>  
EOE;
   }

    if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
        $link = mysql_connect("0.0.0.0", $username, $password) or die (mysql_error());


         $db_selected = mysql_select_db('tschauss', $link);
        if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
        mysql_query(" UPDATE Employer SET eid='$eid' , compname='$compname' , address='$address' , phone='$phone' , email='$email' , position='$position' , description= '$description' , location= '$state' , skill1= '$skill1' , experience1= '$experience1' , skill2= '$skill2' , experience2= '$experience2' , skill3= '$skill3' , experience3= '$experience3' , need= '$need' WHERE eid='$eid'") or die ("Query has failed us" . mysql_error());
        echo "Record updated <br>";
        mysql_close($link);


       $sql = "update into Employer (EmployerID, CompName, Address, Phone, Email, PosTitle, Description, Location, Skill1, Experience1, Skill2, Experience2, Skill3, Experience3, Need ) values ('$eid', '$compname', '$address', '$phone', '$email', '$position', '$description', '$location', '$skill1', '$experience1', '$skill2', '$experience2', '$skill3', '$experience3', '$need')";
        if ($db->query ($sql) == TRUE)
        {
           mysql_query(" UPDATE Employer SET eid='$eid' , compname='$compname' , address='$address' , phone='$phone' , email='$email' , position=$'position' , description= '$description' , location= '$state' , skill1= '$skill1' , experience1= '$experience1' , skill2= '$skill2' , experience2= '$experience2' , skill3= '$skill3' , experience3= '$experience3' , need= '$need' WHERE eid='$eid'");
            echo "Record updated 2 <br>";
        } 
    }

    $sql = "SELECT EmployerID, CompName, Address, Phone, Email, PosTitle, Description, Location, Skill1, Experience1, Skill2, Experience2, Skill3, Experience3, Need FROM Employer";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "EmployerID: " . $row["EmployerID"] . " - Company Name: " . $row["CompName"] . " - Address: " . $row["Address"] . " - Phone: " . $row["Phone"] . " - Email: " . $row["Email"] . "<br>" . "Position Title: " . $row["PosTitle"] . " - Description: " . $row["Description"] . " - Location: " . $row["Location"] . " - Skill 1: " . $row["Skill1"] . " - Experience 1: " . $row["Experience1"] . " - Skill 2: " . $row["Skill2"] . " - Experience 2: " . $row["Experience2"] . " - Skill 3: " . $row["Skill3"] . " - Experience 3: " . $row["Experience3"] . " - Need: " . $row["Need"];

        echo " <form action=\"$thisPHP\" method='post' style=\"display:inline\" >";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='eid' value='$eid'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='btnEdit' value='Edit'> ";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='btnDelete' value='Delete'>  </form>" . "<br>";
    }

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $db->close();
?>
```

(end of code)

If you could please view my code and give me any feedback, greatly appreciated!

(employer.sql) - (data redacted, personal information is now NULL):

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.9deb1.lucid~ppa.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 30, 2017 at 01:31 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log
-- PHP Version: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `NULL` 
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Employer`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employer` (
  `EmployerID` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `CompName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `PosTitle` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Skill1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Experience1` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Skill2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Experience2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Skill3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Experience3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Need` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Employer`
--

INSERT INTO `Employer` (`EmployerID`, `CompName`, `Address`, `Phone`, `Email`, `PosTitle`, `Description`, `Location`, `Skill1`, `Experience1`, `Skill2`, `Experience2`, `Skill3`, `Experience3`, `Need`) VALUES
(0, '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', 0, '', 0, '');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */

;
```

Comment: the issue explains itself , you don't have the `eid` column in your table.

Comment: the error is self-explanatory. the column does not exist in your table

Comment: Don't just dump your whole application here. Also please, **please** learn about `for` loops and arrays. You've repeated the state picker at least twice. That can be cleaned up to like four lines of code with the right approach.

Comment: This is also a confused collection of database calls, some using PDO (?) and others using the out-dated `mysql_query`. None of it is escaped correctly.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: seems like you need to use the proper column name -> delete from Employer where EmployerID=$eid. But it's not the worst part of what you showed us... Beside that, IMHO you should 1/ use prepared statements 2/ check all input data before you use it 3/ split scripts when possible as it's easier to read/maintain

Comment: I'm working with my first PHP/MySQL assignment. I'm attempting to learn this as much as I can. But, please mind my rookie mistakes... this is all new to me (PHP/MySQL).

Comment: @TheHouse : I'm pretty sure we all keep in mind your need-to-be-improved-php-skills as we all went through this before (long time ago, in a far far galaxy for some of us... ^^) and that we keep on learning every day! that's why googling about errors and reading tutorials and fetching through older answers is very useful...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've sat on youtube/forums with no luck when i'm learning this. The stackoverflow community always has the answers.

Comment: I was able to now delete one record, after that, nothing happens... I also updated the edit function:// $sql = "select * from Employer where EmployerID='$eid'"; // I'm assuming this is due to how I wrote the code?

Comment: Anyone answering this, please [check this possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275283/php-form-edit-and-delete-arent-executing-database) before doing so, to prevent duplicate effort.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection. 
Now to your error:

The table Employer has no column eid:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employer` (
  `EmployerID` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `CompName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `PosTitle` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Skill1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Experience1` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Skill2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Experience2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Skill3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Experience3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Need` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The column name you refering is named `EmployerID`.

So your statement must be `delete from Employer where EmployerID=$eid`.

And because employerId is an int not a character field you do not need the single quotes arround.

The same error is in the following `select` statement.

Then you mix `mysqli_*` API and `mysql_*` (`mysql_errr()`). Change it to `mysqli_error`

Comment: Ahh yes, I see that mistake now. Thank you. I was able to now delete one record, after that, nothing happens. I also updated the edit function:// $sql = "select * from Employer where EmployerID='$eid'"; // I'm assuming this is due to how I wrote the code.