# Edit and delete aren't executing in the database in my PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Everything in this code seems to work just fine, except when I try to edit/delete already queried data. I'm new to PHP and MySQL please give me any advice or direction... trying to have this run correctly.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = tschauss;
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "tschauss";

    // Create connection
    $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $cdb->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully <br>";

    $thisPHP = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    if (!isset($_POST['btnEdit'])) {
        echo <<<EOT
        <form action="$thisPHP" method="POST"><br>
        Employer ID: <input type="text" name="eid"><br>
        Company Name: <input type="text" name="compname"><br>
        Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
        Phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br> 
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Position: <input type="text" name="position"> Description: <input type="text" name="description"> 
        Location: <select name="state" id="state">
            <option value="">--</option>
            <option value="AL">AL</option> 
            <option value="AK">AK</option> 
            <option value="AZ">AZ</option> 
            <option value="AR">AR</option> 
            <option value="CA">CA</option> 
            <option value="CO">CO</option> 
            <option value="CT">CT</option> 
            <option value="DE">DE</option> 
            <option value="FL">FL</option> 
            <option value="GA">GA</option> 
            <option value="HI">HI</option> 
            <option value="ID">ID</option> 
            <option value="IL">IL</option> 
            <option value="IN">IN</option> 
            <option value="IA">IA</option> 
            <option value="KS">KS</option> 
            <option value="KY">KY</option> 
            <option value="LA">LA</option> 
            <option value="ME">ME</option> 
            <option value="MD">MD</option> 
            <option value="MA">MA</option> 
            <option value="MI">MI</option> 
            <option value="MN">MN</option> 
            <option value="MS">MS</option> 
            <option value="MO">MO</option> 
            <option value="MT">MT</option> 
            <option value="NE">NE</option> 
            <option value="NV">NV</option> 
            <option value="NH">NH</option> 
            <option value="NJ">NJ</option> 
            <option value="NM">NM</option> 
            <option value="NY">NY</option> 
            <option value="NC">NC</option> 
            <option value="ND">ND</option> 
            <option value="OH">OH</option> 
            <option value="OK">OK</option> 
            <option value="OR">OR</option> 
            <option value="PA">PA</option> 
            <option value="RI">RI</option> 
            <option value="SC">SC</option> 
            <option value="SD">SD</option> 
            <option value="TN">TN</option> 
            <option value="TX">TX</option> 
            <option value="UT">UT</option> 
            <option value="VT">VT</option> 
            <option value="WA">WA</option> 
            <option value="WV">WV</option> 
            <option value="WI">WI</option> 
            <option value="WY">WY</option> 
            <option value="DC">DC</option> 
        </select> <br>
        Skill: <select name="skill1">
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience1">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Skill: <select name="skill2">
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience2">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Skill: <select name="skill3">
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience3">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Need: <input type="radio" name="need" value="Urgent" checked> Urgent (<1 Month) <br>
             <input type="radio" name="need" value="Soon"> Soon (1-3 Months) <br>
             <input type="radio" name="need" value="Upcoming"> Upcoming (3+ Month) <br>
        <input type="submit" name="btnAdd" value="Add"> <br>
        <hr>
        </form>  
EOT;
    }

    $eid = $_POST["eid"];
    $compname = $_POST["compname"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $location = $_POST["state"];
    $skill1 = $_POST["skill1"];
    $experience1 = $_POST["experience1"];
    $skill2 = $_POST["skill2"];
    $experience2 = $_POST["experience2"];
    $skill3 = $_POST["skill3"];
    $experience3 = $_POST["experience3"];
    $need = $_POST["need"];
        
    if (isset($_POST['btnAdd'])){
        if (!empty($eid)){
            // Form sql string
            $location = $_POST["state"];
            $sql = "insert into Employer (EmployerID, CompName, Address, Phone, Email, PosTitle, Description, Location, Skill1, Experience1, Skill2, Experience2, Skill3, Experience3, Need) values ('$eid', '$compname', '$address', '$phone', '$email', '$position', '$description', '$location', '$skill1', '$experience1', '$skill2', '$experience2', '$skill3', '$experience3', '$need')";
            if ($db->query ($sql) == TRUE) {
                echo "Record added <br>";
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['btnDelete'])) {
        $eid= $_POST['eid'];
        $sql = "delete from Employer where EmployerID='$eid'";
        echo mysql_error();
        if ($db->query ($sql) == TRUE)
        {
            echo "Record deleted <br>";
        }
    } 

   if (isset($_POST['btnEdit'])) {
        $sql = "select * from Employer where EmployerID='$eid'";
        if (($result = $db->query ($sql)) == TRUE)
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $eid = $row["EmployerID"];
                $compname = $row["CompName"];
                $address = $row["Address"];
                $phone = $row["Phone"];
                $email = $row["Email"];
                $position = $row["PosTitle"];
                $description = $row["Description"];
                $location = $row["Location"];
                $skill1 = $row["Skill1"];
                $experience1 = $row["Experience1"];
                $skill2 = $row["Skill2"];
                $experience2 = $row["Experience2"];
                $skill3 = $row["Skill3"];
                $experience3 = $row["Experience3"];
                $need = $row["Need"];
            }
        }
   
        
        echo <<<EOE
        <form action="$thisPHP" method="POST">
        Employer ID: <input type="text" name="eid" value='$eid'> 
        Company Name: <input type="text" name="compname" value='$compname'> 
        Address: <input type="text" name="address" value='$address'> 
        Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" value='$phone'> 
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" value='$email'><br>
        Position: <input type="text" name="position" value='$position'> 
        Description: <input type="text" name="description" value='$description'> 
        Location: <select name="state" id="state" value='$location'>
            <option value="">--</option>
            <option value="AL">AL</option> 
            <option value="AK">AK</option> 
            <option value="AZ">AZ</option> 
            <option value="AR">AR</option> 
            <option value="CA">CA</option> 
            <option value="CO">CO</option> 
            <option value="CT">CT</option> 
            <option value="DE">DE</option> 
            <option value="FL">FL</option> 
            <option value="GA">GA</option> 
            <option value="HI">HI</option> 
            <option value="ID">ID</option> 
            <option value="IL">IL</option> 
            <option value="IN">IN</option> 
            <option value="IA">IA</option> 
            <option value="KS">KS</option> 
            <option value="KY">KY</option> 
            <option value="LA">LA</option> 
            <option value="ME">ME</option> 
            <option value="MD">MD</option> 
            <option value="MA">MA</option> 
            <option value="MI">MI</option> 
            <option value="MN">MN</option> 
            <option value="MS">MS</option> 
            <option value="MO">MO</option> 
            <option value="MT">MT</option> 
            <option value="NE">NE</option> 
            <option value="NV">NV</option> 
            <option value="NH">NH</option> 
            <option value="NJ">NJ</option> 
            <option value="NM">NM</option> 
            <option value="NY">NY</option> 
            <option value="NC">NC</option> 
            <option value="ND">ND</option> 
            <option value="OH">OH</option> 
            <option value="OK">OK</option> 
            <option value="OR">OR</option> 
            <option value="PA">PA</option> 
            <option value="RI">RI</option> 
            <option value="SC">SC</option> 
            <option value="SD">SD</option> 
            <option value="TN">TN</option> 
            <option value="TX">TX</option> 
            <option value="UT">UT</option> 
            <option value="VT">VT</option> 
            <option value="WA">WA</option> 
            <option value="WV">WV</option> 
            <option value="WI">WI</option> 
            <option value="WY">WY</option> 
            <option value="DC">DC</option> 
        </select> <br>
        Skill: <select name="skill1" value='$skill1'>
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience1" value='$experience1'>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Skill: <select name="skill2" value='$skill2'>
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience2" value='$experience'>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Skill: <select name="skill3" value='$skill3'>
            <option value="Skill1">Skill 1</option>
            <option value="Skill2">Skill 2</option>
            <option value="Skill3">Skill 3</option>
            </select>
        Experience: <select name="experience3" value='$experience3'>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1-3</option>
            <option value="3">3-5</option>
            <option value="5">5-10</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select><br>
        Need: <input type="radio" name="need" value="Urgent" checked value='$name'> Urgent (<1 Month) <br>
             <input type="radio" name="need" value="Soon" value='$name'> Soon (1-3 Months) <br>
             <input type="radio" name="need" value="Upcoming" value='$name'> Upcoming (3+ Month) <br>
        <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update"> <br>
        <hr>
        </form>  
EOE;
   }

    if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
        $link = mysql_connect("0.0.0.0", $username, $password) or die (mysql_error());
         
         
         $db_selected = mysql_select_db('tschauss', $link);
        if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
        mysql_query(" UPDATE Employer SET eid='$eid' , compname='$compname' , address='$address' , phone='$phone' , email='$email' , position='$position' , description= '$description' , location= '$state' , skill1= '$skill1' , experience1= '$experience1' , skill2= '$skill2' , experience2= '$experience2' , skill3= '$skill3' , experience3= '$experience3' , need= '$need' WHERE eid='$eid'") or die ("Query has failed us" . mysql_error());
        echo "Record updated <br>";
        mysql_close($link);
        
        
       $sql = "update into Employer (EmployerID, CompName, Address, Phone, Email, PosTitle, Description, Location, Skill1, Experience1, Skill2, Experience2, Skill3, Experience3, Need ) values ('$eid', '$compname', '$address', '$phone', '$email', '$position', '$description', '$location', '$skill1', '$experience1', '$skill2', '$experience2', '$skill3', '$experience3', '$need')";
        if ($db->query ($sql) == TRUE)
        {
           mysql_query(" UPDATE Employer SET eid='$eid' , compname='$compname' , address='$address' , phone='$phone' , email='$email' , position=$'position' , description= '$description' , location= '$state' , skill1= '$skill1' , experience1= '$experience1' , skill2= '$skill2' , experience2= '$experience2' , skill3= '$skill3' , experience3= '$experience3' , need= '$need' WHERE eid='$eid'");
            echo "Record updated 2 <br>";
        } 
    }

    $sql = "SELECT EmployerID, CompName, Address, Phone, Email, PosTitle, Description, Location, Skill1, Experience1, Skill2, Experience2, Skill3, Experience3, Need FROM Employer";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "EmployerID: " . $row["EmployerID"] . " - Company Name: " . $row["CompName"] . " - Address: " . $row["Address"] . " - Phone: " . $row["Phone"] . " - Email: " . $row["Email"] . "<br>" . "Position Title: " . $row["PosTitle"] . " - Description: " . $row["Description"] . " - Location: " . $row["Location"] . " - Skill 1: " . $row["Skill1"] . " - Experience 1: " . $row["Experience1"] . " - Skill 2: " . $row["Skill2"] . " - Experience 2: " . $row["Experience2"] . " - Skill 3: " . $row["Skill3"] . " - Experience 3: " . $row["Experience3"] . " - Need: " . $row["Need"];
        
        echo " <form action=\"$thisPHP\" method='post' style=\"display:inline\" >";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='eid' value='$eid'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='btnEdit' value='Edit'> ";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='btnDelete' value='Delete'>  </form>" . "<br>";
    }
        
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $db->close();
?>
```

/// -- DATABASE BELOW --- ///

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.9deb1.lucid~ppa.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 30, 2017 at 01:31 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.12.04.1-log
-- PHP Version: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `tschauss`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `Employer`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employer` (
  "EmployerID" int(60) NOT NULL,
  `CompName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `PosTitle` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `Skill1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Experience1` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Skill2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Experience2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Skill3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Experience3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Need` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Employer`
--

INSERT INTO `Employer` (`EmployerID`, `CompName`, `Address`, `Phone`, `Email`, `PosTitle`, `Description`, `Location`, `Skill1`, `Experience1`, `Skill2`, `Experience2`, `Skill3`, `Experience3`, `Need`) VALUES
(0, '', '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', 0, '', 0, '');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: update syntax : **UPDATE Table set Col = Value,col2=value2....***

Comment: `$sql = "update into`  ???

Comment: `$cdb->connect_error` ??? The variable holding the connection is `$db`

Comment: I think you might need to go back to the drawing board with this form. Hacking at it will just make it even more difficult to maintain

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Ah, ok, I will delete previous comment

Comment: Please don't post this giant chunk of code over and over again. It's very important to present a **minimal** example of the problem you're trying to solve. If you have fifty queries and they're all busted that's fine, we all have days like that, but use **one** as an example. Don't post all fifty.

Comment: @TheHouse : don't you think you should have taken advices from your (almost) same  [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273370/error-when-deleting-or-editing-form-data-from-database-php-mysql) ? split to portions to debug, then put it back all together if **really** needed...

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I was working on the code and I was stuck with no results. Seeing if a few others could assist. Not sure if this works like yahoo answers when everything is pushed to the bottom of the updates, never to see the light of day again. @tadman thank you for that advice. I will look at those links right now.

Comment: I'm honestly trying to have the program work as it is currently and then altering it/advancing it in the future. trying to start with a "rough draft"

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of the question you asked an hour previously?

Comment: The original issue of the first posting you're speaking of was fixed. I'm trying to see if anyone can understand why my secondary issue, the updating / detention will not do anything now. @halfer

Comment: OK. The titles give the strong impression they're identical, so I would suggest you change the other one. We discourage error messages being posted as images anyway - please delete that image, and put in the error message as text, using a quote block (`>` creates a quote). Thanks.

Comment: That error is resolved. Now it's not executing the command for edit or delete.

Comment: Please don't deface your questions

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Comment: Since apparently you didn't understand the first time, I'll say it again: Do. Not. Vandalize. Your. Posts. It's the same idea as building someone's house, then deciding that, because you built it, you can do whatever you want to it, and knocking a wall down. Just because you created it doesn't mean that you can do anything you want; you agreed when you posted this to give Stack Overflow an irrevocable license to use the question however they wanted -- like selling that house you built -- and now you're trying to destroy it -- like knocking down a wall when someone lives there. Don't do it.

Comment: Regarding the two questions, I still don't understand how the previous question is not a dup. This is important for Stack Overflow, where we're trying to curate a set of useful, non-duplicated questions for future users. Unlike Reddit and the rest of them, we're a bit choosy about what stays open and what does not. Don't take it to heart - it is the reason why Stack Overflow is so successful, and why it has thousands of volunteers maintaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `mysql_connect()` in the update clause of the code. If your PHP version is 7 and above it will not work (will work for 5.5 and 5.6 versions but with a warning) as it is deprecated.

> Warning
>
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> ```
> mysqli_connect()
> PDO::__construct()
> ```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

I don't see the point in establishing a new connection while editing when there is a database connection that was made in the beginning of the script. Use the same functions used to insert data to the database from your script:

```
$db->query("UPDATE tablename SET column_name = value");
// to check no. of rows affected by the previous query 
$db->affected_rows()
```

Comment: Not entirely right - if an extension is deprecated it will still work, and the deprecation notices can be suppressed. So `mysql_connect` will work fine on 5.5 and 5.6. It will stop working from 7.0.

Comment: That's what I meant. Changed my answer accordingly.